# What encoding I should use in editor (NetBeans), if I were intend to print non-english character

Tags: java

I try to set the encoding of my editor to UTF-16. (Java String store the data in UTF-16 internally, right?)

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/helloworld.png](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/helloworld.png)

And I type the following code

```
package helloworld;

/**
 *
 * @author yan-cheng.cheok
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("我爱你");
        System.out.println("\u6587\u4EF6\u79CD\u7C7B");
    }

}
```

However, the output is not what I expected :

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/helloworld1.png](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/helloworld1.png)

```
我爱你�
文件种类�
```

I try to change the editor encoding format to UTF-8, it works this time!

```
我爱你
文件种类
```

May I know why I need to change the editor encoding format to UTF-8 but not UTF-16? Isn't Java String store the data in UTF-16 internally?

Comment: Don't know how to solve your problem but how Java stores the String internally has no importance at all and shouldn't concern you.  The String class allow to get both "char" (max 16 bit per char) and codepoints (32 bit / codepoint) and that wouldn't change at all, no matter if String internall use UTF-8 or UTF-16 or some Unicode-extended-version-of-EBCDIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a limitation of the underlaying platform ( Windows in this case ) which doesn't fully support UTF-16

Try investigating around this:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/TextEncodingFOW

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4163515

They're not definitive answers but may lead you.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to store those string in a properties file.

Those string will be stored in unicode format, you can type them in your native language (japanese for example) and after that run the native2ascii command to convert them to unicode...

The advantage with that is that everyone will be able to open the .java and .jsp files... if they want to work with the phrases, then they open the properties file...

Comment: I know. I just want the explanation why the above doesn't work.